# Gating error in quickblox ("quickblox unreadMessageCount is not defined")

Tags: javascript, java, quickblox

I want to access total unread message count. the code I used in my **rails app** is

````
    function unreadMessageCount(){
        Set<String> dialogsIds = new HashSet<String>(){{ add("56f3fac3a0eb4786ae00003f"); add("56f3f546a28f9affc0000033"); }};
        QBChatService.getTotalUnreadMessagesCount(dialogsIds, new QBEntityCallback<Integer>() {
            @Override public void onSuccess(Integer total, Bundle params) {
                Log.i(TAG, "total unread messages: " + total);
                Log.i(TAG, "dialog Unread1: " + 
                params.getInt("56f3fac3a0eb4786ae00003f"));
                Log.i(TAG, "dialog Unread2: " + 
                params.getInt("56f3f546a28f9affc0000033"));
            }
            @Override public void onError(QBResponseException responseException) { }
        });
    } ```
In js console I am gating "unreadMessageCount is not defined".
````

Comment: This code for android not for js

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = {chat_dialog_ids: ["12788459823458761223123124"]};
QB.chat.message.unreadCount(params, function(err, res) {
    if(err){

    }else{

    }
});
```